# Is there a more clear description of SciPy's implementation of the Jaccard-Needham (Dis)similiarity formula?

Tags: python, scipy, distance, scipy-spatial

I have reviewed SciPy's documentation explaining their implementation formula of the Jaccard-Needham dissimilarity function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html#scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard. However, I cannot find anything that explains what the subscript "TF" or FT" stand for, in the formula below:

[image]

Comment: I believe that this function is both incorrectly documented and implemented. There is [an issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12174) on GitHub about this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the documentation states this method is for Boolean arrays, T and F must stand for "true" and "false". "True" would be returned if the kth element in each string are equal, "False" otherwise.